# How to access laravel valet project from local network?

Tags: laravel

I built a laravel project in my desktop folder and running it using valet on project-name.dev . How can I access it from local network ? My IP address is 192.168.1.5 ,I'm using a mac and I tried below code but It gives me a error in my project. Is there any different solution ?

```
php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.5 --port 80
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You forgot the equals sign in your command. It should work like this:

```
php artisan serve --port=80 --host=192.168.1.5
```

To connect any of your local network devices to your mac you can type into their browser's address bar:

```
192.168.1.5:80
```

Answer (score 10):

You can follow the step below

1. Make valet site unsecure 1st using  `valet unsecure sitename`
2. Run `valet share`

A publicly accessible URL will be inserted into your clipboard and is ready to paste directly into your browser. That's it.

Please note

> valet share does not currently support sharing sites that have been
>   secured using the valet secure command.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet#sharing-sites

[image]

Comment: You will probably experience rate limit errors this way if you dont pay for ngrok. php artisan serve works a lot better in LAN context.

Comment: You don't need to make the site unsecured. Just go to the secured (or unsecured) site in your machine and do `valet share` and it's done

Answer (score 9):

You can do that by using `--host=0.0.0.0`. By using `0.0.0.0`, you don't need to hardcode your IP address. It will automatically point to your IP address, even if it changed at some point, maybe when you connect to a different network.

So you type

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
```

You can now access your app using your browser or on another computer in the same network.

```
http://192.168.1.5:80
```

Comment: Both answers are basically the same ( so I marked first answer as accepted , above answer was given few minutes earlier and I used that one , thanks )

Comment: This one is slightly better as it dont use hardcoded IP. But idea is the same.